# aws s3 - SdkInterruptedException

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

Getting an exception `com.amazonaws.http.timers.client.SdkInterruptedException` on executing below line of code when deployed as a Spark job in AWS EMR.

```
S3Object response = s3client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(s3URI.getBucket(), s3URI.getKey()));
```

The sdk version, code and stack trace are mentioned below. What could be the issue and how to resolve this?

**Version Info**

- Java version: 1.8
- AWS SDK Version: 1.11.1026

**Dependency**

- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bundle:jar:1.11.1026

**Code**

```
public static ByteArrayOutputStream getS3Object(String path) {
  AmazonS3 s3client = null;
  try {
    AmazonS3URI s3URI = new AmazonS3URI(path);
    s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient();
    S3Object response = s3client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(s3URI.getBucket(), s3URI.getKey()));
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = response.getObjectContent().read(buffer)) != -1) {
      byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    response.close();
    return byteArrayOutputStream;
  } catch (AbortedException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.err.println("AWS call interrupted retrying " + e);
  } finally {
    if (s3client != null) {
      s3client.shutdown();
    }
  }
  throw new RuntimeException("s3 object is null");
}
```

**Stack trace**

```
com.amazonaws.AbortedException: 
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleInterruptedException(AmazonHttpClient.java:880)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:757)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:715)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:697)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:561)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:541)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5456)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5403)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1524)
com.example.S3Utils.getS3Object(S3Utils.java:78)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.http.timers.client.SdkInterruptedException
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.checkInterrupted(AmazonHttpClient.java:935)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.checkInterrupted(AmazonHttpClient.java:921)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1115)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:814)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:781)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:755)
... 53 more
```

Comment: You are using the AWS SDK for Java V1. This SDK version is on path to deprecation. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/announcing-end-of-support-for-aws-sdk-for-java-v1-x-on-december-31-2025/. You should update to V2 as soon as possible.  I will post the code below that you should be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an SDK version that is on path to deprecation as mentioned in my comment. Now to get an S3 object using AWS SDK for Java V2, you can use this code. If you do not know how to get up and running with V2, see DEV Guide:

[Developer Guide - AWS SDK for Java 2.x](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html)

```
package com.example.s3;

// snippet-start:[s3.java2.getobjectdata.main]
// snippet-start:[s3.java2.getobjectdata.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.ResponseBytes;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetObjectResponse;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
// snippet-end:[s3.java2.getobjectdata.import]

/**
 * Before running this Java V2 code example, set up your development
 * environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For more information, see the following documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */

public class GetObjectData {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String usage = """

                Usage:
                    <bucketName> <keyName> <path>

                Where:
                    bucketName - The Amazon S3 bucket name.\s
                    keyName - The key name.\s
                    path - The path where the file is written to.\s
                """;

        if (args.length != 3) {
            System.out.println(usage);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String bucketName = args[0];
        String keyName = args[1];
        String path = args[2];
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        getObjectBytes(s3, bucketName, keyName, path);
    }

    public static void getObjectBytes(S3Client s3, String bucketName, String keyName, String path) {
        try {
            GetObjectRequest objectRequest = GetObjectRequest
                    .builder()
                    .key(keyName)
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .build();

            ResponseBytes<GetObjectResponse> objectBytes = s3.getObjectAsBytes(objectRequest);
            byte[] data = objectBytes.asByteArray();

            // Write the data to a local file.
            File myFile = new File(path);
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            os.write(data);
            System.out.println("Successfully obtained bytes from an S3 object");
            os.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
// snippet-end:[s3.java2.getobjectdata.main]
```

You can find the POM in the AWS Code Example Github here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/s3

Comment: Thanks @smac2020. We have other code making use of AWS SDK for Java v1.x. Will there be any code change required in those code as well in order to migrate from AWS SDK for v1.x to v2.x?

Comment: Yes there is a migration guide. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/migration.html. You should replace all V1 to V2 ASAP.

Comment: we tried upgrading the aws sdk version (```software.amazon.awssdk:s3:2.24.5```) and used your code. Now we see this exception ```software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from any of the providers in the chain....Interrupted waiting to refresh a cached value., InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(): Interrupted waiting to refresh a cached value.```. The use case is, we invoke an API with this S3 object. We get this exception after the server returns 500 - Internal Server Error and we try with getting the S3 object. What could be the issue?

Comment: This means you creds cannot be located "software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from any of the providers in the chain". To setup your creds -- see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials-chain.html

Comment: We iterate through a list of S3 path and then get the current S3 object and then we upload this S3 object as a multi-part file invoking an API. Given five S3 objects path, if the API fails with 500 server error while trying with third S3 object, then we face this exception while trying to resume with fourth S3 object. (***Note:*** The instance is configured via IAM role and we don't explicitly configure the credentials). Also tried with Retry Policy (STANDARD) on S3 Client, but still same issue. What could be the issue?